Is there a way to simplify $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos x}{A}\right)$?
Is there a way to simplify the following:
$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos x}{A}\right)$$
I'm thinking something along the line of pulling $A$ out and then getting $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$ which would be $x$ multiplied I guess by $$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{A}\right)$$
so
$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos x}{A}\right) = x\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{A}\right) $$
Can $\cos^{-1}$ be distributed that way? Is there anything else clever that can be done?

No you cannot do that. Also there must be some conditions on $A$ I guess.

Yes, A is less than or equal to 1, and practically does not go below 0.5.  Actually, know that I think about it A lies between or is equal to $\cosx$ and 1.

If $x$ is small you can use the Taylor series for an approximation.  Otherwise nothing like this works

@rdemo If $\frac12 <A<1$ (per your comment) then $\frac{1}{A}>1$ which is a problem for arccos. Hint: just check your conjecture numerically (that really should be the first thing you try). If it seems to work, then try to prove it; if it doesn't (but you think it should), try to understand why it doesn't (in this case, maybe try $A=2$ and think about it geometrically, for example consider angles in a polygon).

I should have mentioned what the ratio cosx/A can be equal to and not just A.  In the physical process A cannot be > 1 (this would violate conservation of energy).  Further, theoretically A cannot be less than cos x.  So, $\cos x <= \frac{\cos x}{A} <= 1$

Assuming $A \geq 1$, why not to use
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos (x)}{A}\right)=\frac \pi 2- \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ (2 n)!}{4^n\,(2 n+1)\, (n!)^2} \left(\frac{\cos (x)}{A}\right)^{2 n+1}$$ which would converge very fast.
And, for small values of $x$ or large values of $A$
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos (x)}{A}\right)=\sec ^{-1}(A)+\frac{x^2}{2 \sqrt{A^2-1}}\Bigg(1-\frac{\left(A^2+2\right) x^2}{12
   \left(A^2-1\right)}+\frac{\left(A^4+28 A^2+16\right)
   x^4}{360 \left(A^2-1\right)^2} +O(x^6) \Bigg)$$

Nope.You can't simplify your original expression.
Max we can go is
$$\cos^{-1}(\frac{\cos x}{A}) =\fracπ2 -\sin^{-1}(\frac{\cos x}{A})$$
Now $\sin^{-1}(x)=-i\ln(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)$
So the expression becomes
$$\fracπ2 +i\ln(\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{\cos x}{A}\bigg)^2} + i\frac{\cos x}{A})$$
For your expression,
$$\cos^{-1}(\frac{\cos x}{A})=x\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{A})$$
Is an equation(not an indetity), which is valid if $-1≤\frac{1}{A}≤1$.

This is not correct.  Just to take $x=1, A=3.7$, LHS$\approx 1.424$, RHS$\approx 1.297$

Yes sir? @RossMillikan I'm really sorry but I didn't understand your comment. Are you presenting a solution to the equation?

I have edited the comment to make it readable, but the equation is false in general.

I'm getting confused.  I've thought about this more and the quotient $\frac{\cos x}{A}$  is also less than or equal to 1, but it is never negative.

@rdemo unless both have equal simultaneously, it won't be positive. Is cos x restricted within two bounds? Presumably $\frac{-π}{2}$ to $\fracπ2$

The bounds on x are 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  It's a physical process and we don't look at negative angles.

No, this is not true at all.  Never mind the bounds, the equation is simply wrong.

@rdemo please add that to the question :)

@RobertIsrael check this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vbntitvtgg there seems to be a solution

@RossMillikan this is an "equation", not an "identity". Maybe there has been some confusion?

@Gwen.  I believe you are the one who is confused.  My post specifically states that I want to simplify an expression.  Then I was wondering if it could be simplified as the equation that I gave. As other posters have stated, the expression in my initial post cannot be simplified to what I thought perhaps it could be.

@rdemo I know that. You can't possibly simplify it. I'm telling that the equation you thought will work will not work. I'm editing my answer alright

@Gwen:  I wasn't aware of this identity between arcsin and ln.  As I said, I'm dealing with a physical process and imaginary numbers shouldn't be possible. It's been many decades since I learned about imaginary numbers. Can your answer be written subject to certain criteria such that "i" can be removed?

@rdemo Sir, honestly, your original expression is way simplified, and easy to compute. All processes that I could think of are getting more and more congested. As one of them suggested, if the angle is reaally small, we can say that $cos (x) \sim 1$ and so the expression becomes $\cos^{-1}\frac1A$ .
